# using array unique with array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the php code as below:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbcsv",$conn);
    $data = array();
    $sql = "select orig,dlvSourceIp from tblcsv group by dlvSourceIp";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     echo '<table border="1px">';
     echo "<tr><td>Dormain</td><td>ip of the domain</td><td>Total Mail</td><td>Mail Fail</td><td>Percentage</td></tr>";
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
             //echo "<tr><td>".$data['orig']."</td><td>".$data['dlvSourceIp']."</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
            $t = $data['orig'];
             $getData = array_unique($t);
             var_dump($getData);
}
?>
```

**Note**

For `$data['orig']` is the array of data that I select it from database it will display: `cat cat dog cat dog`. I want output like this:`cat dog` that why I use array unique.

**The problem:**

I got the error message `array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\CountLine_CSV\csv2mysql.php on line 21` How do I fix it? Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: You fix it by passing an array in parameter 1 when calling `array_unique` instead of a null value ... the error message is pretty clear. The value of `$t` in your code is quite obviously null.

Comment: try doing `print_r($data['orig'])` . it appears as though the variable `$data['orig']` is not an array. It must be an array to use that function.

Comment: Could you add a little context as to what you're trying to do, and what the content of `orig` will be?

Comment: @rdlowrey duh, deleting tht stupid comment in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: @bfavaretto No problem -- I do stupid stuff from time to time and try really hard to admit it when I do :)

Answer (score 1):

Your array was stored into the table as a string value (so I think).  You need to grab the entry, `explode` it and create an array, then use `array_unique` to get your desired effect.  Try the following and see if it works:

```
$t = $data['orig']
$array = explode(" ", $t);
$array = array_unique($array);
print_r($array);
```

Also, look into using MySQLi or PDO for your query.

So in full, something like the following should suffice:

```
<?php   
    $mysqli_connection = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli_connection->connect_errno) {
        echo ("Connection Failure");
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT orig, dlvSourceIp FROM tblcsv GROUP BY dlvSourceIp";
    echo '<table border="1px">';
    echo "<tr><td>Dormain</td><td>ip of the domain</td><td>Total Mail</td><td>Mail Fail</td><td>Percentage</td></tr>";
    while($data = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $t = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($data['orig']);
        $array = explode(" ", $t);
        $array = array_unique($array);
        // Do something with the array, or:
        print_r($array);
    }
    $sql->free();
    $mysqli_connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: You are right, except for the first sentence. MySQL does not have an array data type, so the data is stored as a string. Maybe it was an PHP array `implode`d before insertion.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I meant to imply the the data was inserted into the table as a string regardless of the user's desire to preserve it as an array.

Comment: See rdlowrey's comment above, and the error message in the question. The query isn't returning any rows. Looks like you wrote a solution to the *next* problem the OP will face after he fixes that! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah, well you seem to be even more correct. Probably should have refreshed and re-read before posting. Regardless, hopefully OG will find this useful for when the time comes.

Comment: Many thanks,but I got the error message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in C:\wamp\www\CountLine_CSV\csv2mysql.php on line 51`. How to fix it?

Comment: Probably because this should use "$mysqli_connection".  I left out the '$', sorry. Here it is corrected: $t = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($data['orig']);